# Download SSIS packages used in SQL jobs for migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

We need to migrate approx 100 SSIS jobs currently on SQL Server 2008R2 to 2012/14/16

How can I download these SSIS packages and later use them while moving jobs on new servers?

Please suggest

Update@

I tried using `dtuitil` but the problem 7 out of 10 packages failes with below error

> Could not load package "\njnbsscncsc " because of error 0xC001 1008.
>   Description: Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.

Comment: Are the packages actually SSIS or are they DTS?  There are lots of tools/methods out there (my favorite is dbatools) for extracting SSIS packages in bulk from a SQL Server.  But it's not a straight path for SSIS.  You have connection strings, improved security in the new model (which breaks things in the old), drivers and more that need to be assessed, migrated and updated.

Comment: @JonathanFite, Is there a way to confirm? I extracted one using dtutil and they are getting saved as dtsx

Comment: do you have the packages deployed on SSISDB? or they are as .dtsx files?

Comment: @EduardoPivaral, they are stored under MSDB. S i guess .dtsx and nothing under SSISDB , this being 2008R2

Comment: Do you get that error on export or when deploying to the target server?

Comment: @TomV - when exporting